# Reassign to a higher-scoped mutable referenced variable within a loop

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

So I'm trying to implement a linked list in Rust to better understand the language and the following is what I came up with.

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::fmt::Debug;
struct Node<T>
where
    T: Debug,
{
    value: T,
    next: Option<Rc<Box<Node<T>>>>,
}

pub struct LinkedList<T>
where
    T: Debug,
{
    start: Option<Rc<Box<Node<T>>>>,
    end: Option<Rc<Box<Node<T>>>>,
}
```

I managed to implement the insert method, but I'm having trouble implementing the traverse method.

```rust
impl<T> LinkedList<T>
where
    T: Debug,
{
    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) {
        let node = Rc::new(Box::new(Node { value, next: None }));

        match &mut self.end {
            None => {
                self.start = Some(Rc::clone(&node));
            }

            Some(ref mut end_node) => {
                if let Some(mutable_node) = Rc::get_mut(end_node) {
                    mutable_node.next = Some(Rc::clone(&node));
                }
            }
        }

        self.end = Some(node);
    }

    pub fn traverse(&mut self) {
        let mut ptr = &mut self.start;

        while let Some(ref mut node_rc) = &mut ptr {
            let inner_ptr = Rc::get_mut(node_rc).unwrap();

            *ptr = inner_ptr.next;
       }
    }
}
```

In the traverse method I'm trying to do the basic, initialize a pointer at start and keep moving the pointer forward at each iteration of the loop, but the above `traverse` implementation gives me the following error

```
rustc: cannot move out of `inner_ptr.next` which is behind a mutable reference
move occurs because `inner_ptr.next` has type `Option<Rc<Box<Node<T>>>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

which made some sense to me, so I tried modifying my code to

```rust
ptr = &mut inner_ptr.next;
```

but now I get a different error stating

```
   |
56 |         while let Some(ref mut node_rc) = &mut ptr {
   |                                           -------- borrow of `ptr` occurs here
...
59 |             ptr = &mut inner_ptr.next;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |             |
   |             assignment to borrowed `ptr` occurs here
   |             borrow later used here
```

I thought I was getting this error because `inner_ptr` is dropped at the end of each loop iteration, so I made the following change to the `traverse` method by having `inner_ptr's` lifetime to equal `ptr's` lifetime, like so

```rust
    pub fn traverse(&mut self) {
        let mut ptr = &mut self.start;
        let mut inner_ptr: &mut Box<Node<T>>;

        while let Some(ref mut node_rc) = &mut ptr {
            inner_ptr = Rc::get_mut(node_rc).unwrap();

            ptr = &mut inner_ptr.next;
       }
    }
```

But, the compiler throws the same error in this case as well. Clearly I'm missing something fundamental here about Rust's borrow mechanism, but I can't figure out what

Comment: There is a problem with your `insert` cause the reference to `end` never can be unique since `self` holds on to it twice, once through `start` and once through `end` so `if let Some(mutable_node) = Rc::get_mut(end_node)` always fails.

Comment: A singly linked list doesn't need `Rc`, `Box` will suffice. In general, too many `Rc::get_mut()`s in the code is a code smell.

Comment: @cafce25 Thanks for pointing that out, but I don't understand how `self` is holding onto `end` twice every time. Only the very first time are `self.start` and `self.end` equal to each other

Comment: The other times if it worked `self.start` would eventually link to `self.end` through the list.

Comment: I don't understand how `self.start` could link to `self.end`
I'm assigning `self.start`only once...
Logging out `self.end` at each iteration reveals to me that `self.end` is null only once so `self.start` is only assigned once

Comment: Not directly but through the chain of `next`s. ie `self.start.next == self.end` or `self.start.next.next == end`… if you add the necessary amount of going through the next field you'll eventually reach a second `Rc` that references the same `Node` as `self.end`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking a mutable reference of `ptr` when you should't.

```rust
pub fn traverse(&mut self) {
    let mut ptr = &mut self.start;

    while let Some(ref mut node_rc) = ptr { // don't take a mutable reference here
        println!("{:?}", node_rc.value);
        let inner_ptr = Rc::get_mut(node_rc).unwrap();

        ptr = &mut inner_ptr.next;
   }
}
```

You don't want to take a mutable reference there because you don't want to borrow it which would prevent you from changing it later.
Instead you want to move it and replace it every loop.

Comment: It compiles with this change. Could you please explain why taking a mutable reference at that place is wrong?

Comment: Added another sentence of explanation, is it clear now? @Riptide